# Postal Framework crash in iPhone but runs successfully in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imap, postal

I have integrated the [Postal framework](https://github.com/snipsco/Postal)  in my sample iOS application for IMAP functionality. NOTE no other functionality just a iOS app and Framework added in it and using only one method and it's runs successfully on simulator but crash in iOS device.Sample code which you can [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kzmkzGzdpcxULbyPja6GMKykkQm50GJs/view?usp=sharing)

Please find the attached crash log from device from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DDmCuyRXUkjzVuJyPIWBFW4EES9QuxHS/view?usp=share_link)

The exception message is:

> Linked against modern SDK, VOIP socket will not wake. Use Local Push Connectivity instead

```
   let postal = Postal(configuration: .yahoo(login: "karamjeetsinghbuttar@yahoo.com", password: PasswordType.plain("xxxxxxxxxx") ))
        
        postal.connect { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("success")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

I have tried al the require solution but yet not able to get any success. Please let me know if someone find out why it's crash in iPhone device or what are possible reason of the crash only on iPhone.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show relevant code and details of the exception message